# Can you sort products by price, starting with the most cheapest in search results?(magento)

Tags: magento, sorting, search

**How would you go about sorting products with the most cheapest first in search results (magento site)?**

I currently have it set to sort by price but it starts with expensive and works its way up. Is there a way to have it the other way around? 
Please give me a solution ..
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly I haven't found a way to change the sort order in the configuration, and others have had the same problem. However, it shouldn't be too tough to change it in an unobtrusive way to get your desired results.

I would start by creating a new module which rewrites `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php`. From here, all you need to do is change the default sort order for the `protected $_direction` variable. See the code below:

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_Block_Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
{
    /**
     * New default direction
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_direction           = 'desc';
}
```

Comment: using addFilters($values)  this should be possible. Check Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Advanced class code

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify collections (kind of dirty) as the variable mentioned in my code is the direction that's used by default.

Comment: well this addFilters is something you need to call at block level not by modifying collection but using class functions.